# getting facebook user ID

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, appmobi

is there ant way to get Facebook user Id by passing the email and password of the user through a graph API....what i want to do is,i want to get the profile details of a particular user..if we know the user id then the details of the particular user can be obtained by the GRAPH API..
https://graph.facebook.com/ID

but i don't know how to get the Facebook user id.....please help me out....
I'm using JavaScript and html5 for mobile applications..both android and ios..and the IDE's are APPMOBI and PHONEGAP

Comment: i would like to know if we can get the user id of a particular user by passing their username and password in the graph api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting an access token by logging in using the username and password, then calling `https://graph.facebook.com/me` and getting the id field. I don't think there's a direct way of getting an id through the API just using the username and password without getting an access token for that user, which would require that the user accept your appId.

Comment: @vishnuagikumar It's more complicated than being able to explain in comments, but you can start here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ Using the javascript API, init, login, then call /me. You'll have to already have an AppID from facebook registered using your domain. If you're not using javascript there's also a PHP, Android and iOS API.